# I am running nodejs App in my main domain in the plesk does any one know how to allow the subdomain to host the nodejs app as well?

Tags: node.js, server, subdomain, plesk

does any one know how to allow the subdomain to host the nodejs app as well ?
currently I have main domain that is hosting nodejs application on the plesk , but I want to create subdomain under that main domain to be able to host different node js app , if possible.

can anyone guide me with this please ?